# How to transpose columns into rows and ensure repetition of rows accordingly in R?

Tags: r, dataset, tidyverse, data-manipulation, transpose

How to transpose the columns and ensure that rows are repeated accordingly?

Dataset `df` has the following data :-

```
Date       Year  Month Day USD  EUR JPY
1994-1-1    1994  1     1   10  20   5
1995-1-1    1995  1     1   12  30   10
```

The expected output is :-

```
Date       Year Month Day Currency Currency/CCY
1994-1-1   1994 1     1   USD      10
1994-1-1   1994 1     1   EUR      20
1994-1-1   1994 1     1   JPY      5
1995-1-1   1995 1     1   USD      12
1995-1-1   1995 1     1   EUR      30
1995-1-1   1995 1     1   JPY      10
```

Comment: Use `pivot_longer()`. `library(tidyr) pivot_longer(df, cols = c(USD, EUR, JPY), names_to = "Currency",  values_to = "Currency/CCY")`.

Comment: In the original dataset there are actually close to 30 columns. In this sample, I have highlighted only three. Is there a way to modify column inclusion based on column numbers?

Comment: Yes, 1:30 or whatever cols you want. or better exclude those you do not need like `-c(a, b, c, etc..)`

Answer (score 2):

with base r we can achieve the same result

```r
# Reshape the data
data_long <- reshape(data, idvar = c("Date", "Year", "Month", "Day"), varying = list(c("USD", "EUR", "JPY")), direction = "long", times = c("USD", "EUR", "JPY"), v.names = "Value")

# Reset column names
colnames(data_long) <- c("Date", "Year", "Month", "Day", "Currency", "Value")

# Order the data by Date
data_long[order(data_long$Date), ]

# covert the date to numeric date
data_long$Date <- as.Date(data_long$Date)

# drop the row names
rownames(data_long) <- NULL

# Output

        Date Year Month Day time Value
1 1994-01-01 1994     1   1  USD    10
2 1995-01-01 1995     1   1  USD    12
3 1994-01-01 1994     1   1  EUR    20
4 1995-01-01 1995     1   1  EUR    30
5 1994-01-01 1994     1   1  JPY     5
6 1995-01-01 1995     1   1  JPY    10
```